# Angular-vs-repeat - Scope value is empty when col-md class is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

Scope value becomes empty when used inside any section which has col-md class. Please refer the plunker in comment. The scope value becomes empty when

```
<div style="visibility:hidden">{{item.text}}</div>
```

line is removed.

Comment: where is plunker??

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/T6Xy3KhuRXBn4MZoLq5K?p=preview

Comment: It is unclear.. please describe more context.

Comment: So the problem is because you're using something called `angular-vs-repeat` which is messing with the repeat. That's the sort of useful information you should include in your question.

Comment: @Duncan sorry for that. Any suggestion to fix this issue.

Comment: @PankajParkar I am using angular-vs-repeat for virtual scrolling. The scope value is not accessible inside a div which has col-md class.

Comment: @aaviss but I can see that working in Plunker,,

Comment: @PankajParkar it will not work after you remove this line <div style="visibility:hidden">{{item.text}}</div>. I have updated the plunker

Comment: @aaviss check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is bug or correct fix, but you can definitely set height to `vs-render` to `20`, does fixed the issue. Just say `vs-repeat="20"`

```
<div class="repeater-container" vs-repeat="20" 
 style="overflow:auto;overflow-anchor: none;">
   <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 bby-padding-top-10">
        <label>{{item.text}}</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[**Plunker Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/EDQ4Ip3TTpcrsrj3luLO?p=preview)

Comment: It worked, thanks. Can you please explain why scope was not accessible inside col-md divs.

Answer (score 0):

col-md-12 col-xs-12 should be child of element with class row

`<div class="repeater-container row" vs-repeat style="overflow:auto;overflow-anchor: none;">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 bby-padding-top-10">
                <label>{{item.text}}</label>
        </div>
</div>`

Comment: I cannot use this since their are many labels smiliar to {{item.text}} which needs to be shown inside col divs –